# what is the mechanism of WebRTC Configuration?

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io, webrtc, peerjs

I am trying to build video chat but unable to understand some piece of code:
I have Found that part of Code From WEBRTC Sample
link:-https://github.com/webrtc/samples/commit/ecca1124803688bf512874188624f6d4538f69d0

```
  var servers = null;
  pc1 = new RTCPeerConnection(servers);
  trace('Created local peer connection object pc1');
  pc1.onicecandidate = function(e) {
    onIceCandidate(pc1, e);
  };
  pc2 = new RTCPeerConnection(servers);
  trace('Created remote peer connection object pc2');
  pc2.onicecandidate = function(e) {
    onIceCandidate(pc2, e);
  };
  pc1.oniceconnectionstatechange = function(e) {
    onIceStateChange(pc1, e);
  };
  pc2.oniceconnectionstatechange = function(e) {
    onIceStateChange(pc2, e);
  };
  pc2.ontrack = gotRemoteStream;
```

What is happening when I am passing `null` value to `RTCPeerConnection()`?

Answer (score 1):

The constructor [RTCPeerConnection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/RTCPeerConnection) accepts a configuration object. Among other things, one of the configurations required by most apps would be [`iceServers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCIceServer).

`iceServers` is a list of STUN or TURN servers. For example, your constructor could look like:

```
  var configuration = { 
     "iceServers": [{ "urls": ["stun:stun.1.google.com:19302"] }] 
  }; 

  myConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);
```

In simple words these STUN and TURN servers help the two peers discover a direct path to each other. However when you leave out the servers, it means the app will be able to discover the peer only within the intranet, or essentially within the set of devices that your computer can interact directly with. *[Citation Needed]*

In any production app, you would most likely have to add the STUN and TURN servers. But since you are referring to the [code](https://github.com/webrtc/samples/blob/gh-pages/src/content/peerconnection/pc1/js/main.js) from a [tutorial](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/pc1/), where connection across internet is not required, you can skip the servers.

Comment: Thanks Sir, i have got the Code sample from webrtc where there was nothing like this so what they are actually trying to do?  link-https://github.com/webrtc/samples/commit/ecca1124803688bf512874188624f6d4538f69d0

Comment: Yup, I found that example while writing the answer. The `null` part works in that example is because you are sharing the stream of your webcam to yourself within the same browser tab. I have had some experience with webRTC where it can work within intranet without the STUN/TURN servers configured.

Comment: So Could you please let me know that how should i have to implement this in app any tutorial?? The Code Sample also not working anymore in Chrome (https problem) .  Thanks........

Comment: That's a broad question, but you can start from [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/webrtc/index.htm). That's where I had started learning it.

Comment: [url](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCIceServer/url) is deprecated. Please point people to [urls](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCIceServer/urls) instead.